# Swift 2: How can I assign a dynamic number of strings to an array of Strings?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, swift2, tvos

**Context:**

I'm attempting to create an app that populates a UICollectionView (tvOS) based on the contents of a folder in a local server I'm running. The way I'm trying to do this (and it may be completely wrong way) is to 'scrape' the html of my server pages.

I have the following property defined:

`let moviesArray: [String] = ["<li>Example 1</li>", "<li>Example 2</li>"]`

My UICollectionView will return the number of UICollectionViewCell's equal to `moviesArray.count` so I need this number (along with additional data that I won't speak to in this question).

**Problem:**

The number of files/folders I add to my server is dynamic and will increase / decrease depending on what movies I add to it or delete from it. This will obviously change the html which is returned.

I have the following piece of code that returns the html of my local server's URL and converts it to a string. I then create a substring of that based on a range, and then split out each individual `<li>` element from the html. Here's the code:

```
     do {

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/Files/movies/")

        // 'contentsOfURL' returns the html code of the page
        let html:String? = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        print(html)

        // creates a substring of 'html' based on a range defined below
        let ulString = html![(html?.startIndex.advancedBy(164))!...(html?.endIndex.advancedBy(-22))!]
        print("<ul> substring is: \(ulString)")

        // Splits each <li> into a separate string
        let liSplit = ulString.characters.split{$0 == "\n"}.map(String.init)
        print("li 1 is: \(liSplit[0])")
        print("li 2 is: \(liSplit[1])")
        print("li 3 is: \(liSplit[2])")

    } catch {
        print("the error is: \(error)")
    }
```

**My Question:**

How can I add or remove `String` objects to `self.moviesArray` based on the number of `<li>` elements that are in the html string which is returned? How will I assign each member of `liSplit` to `self.moviesArray` if it is a dynamic number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare you `moviesArray` as variable, not as constant and initialize it:

```
var moviesArray = [String]()
```

Then you can go ahead and simply add all the retrieved element to it:

```
moviesArray += liSplit
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Array in Objective-C,
**1) `NSArray` 
2) `NSMutableArray`**

You can't add objects to or remove objects from NSArray.
You can add objects to or remove objects from NSMutableArray.

In swift, we have only one Array, i.e. `Array`
e.g. `Array<String> or [String], Array<NSURL> or [NSURL], etc`

If you declare array with `var` keyword, it will be mutable version, so you can add or remove objects
**e.g.**

```
var arrayString : Array<String> = Array()
arrayString.append("Hitendra")
arrayString.append("Solanki")
```

If you declare array with `let` keyword, it will not be mutable version, so you can't add or remove objects
**e.g.**

```
var arrayString : Array<String> = Array()
arrayString.append("Hitendra")//not allowed
arrayString.append("Solanki")//not allowed
```

So just change the

```
let moviesArray: [String] = ["<li>Example 1</li>", "<li>Example 2</li>"]
```

**to**

```
var moviesArray: [String] = ["<li>Example 1</li>", "<li>Example 2</li>"]
```

and use following lines,

```
let liSplit = ulString.characters.split{$0 == "\n"}.map(String.init)

for listItem in liSplit {
moviesArray.append(listItem)
}
```